# como llamar un componente vue 3 dentro del script setup de otro componente?

Tags: javascript, vue3

quiero llamar un componente vue3 en el scrip stup de otro componente ....como podria hacerlo? no quiro llamarlo en el template.Componet solo lo que devuelve un "hola mundo"....

```
<script setup>

import A from '../components/component.vue'

import { h, ref} from 'vue'

$('#container').h(<component>)

</script>

<template>

    <div class="app-content content ">
        <div class="content-overlay"></div>
        <div class="content-wrapper container-xxl p-0">
            <div class="content-header row"> </div>
            <div class="content-body">
                <div id="container">


          </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</template>
```

Comment: ¿Y el "Hola mundo" es una función no? ¿por qué no usa emits? En mayor caso un composable es perfecto

Comment: y en el caso que usara emits ?

Comment: La documentación indica los pasos a seguir: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events